# Multiple endpoints with one WSDL

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl file and existing endpoint related to this wsdl. Is there any way to define another Endpoint using the same wsdl, but with different logic and published with different address?

Comment: Does the endpoint exist? If you type it in your browser do you go to the page? If not, then no.

Comment: I think you can have multiple end-points, each for one operation

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you post your work here and let us know, what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: You can just copy the WSDL file.  In the copy, the endpoint addres, if it was for example http://127.0.0.1/ThisFunctionality?wsdl change it to http://127.0.0.1/ThatFunctionality?wsdl  obviously you have to add the web service in your code to handle it which might be as simple as cling the existing code or just the web service class and annotating it with "ThatFunctionality"

Comment: I can't copy the WSDL file. It has to be the same wsdl